# Gridview with multiple columns of checkboxes selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a Gridview with checkboxes in my application.
Here is the format:
[image]

In the gridview if header checkbox is checked then all subsequent chekboxes under that should also be checked or unchecked as the case of header chekbox.

for this I am using java script function as.

```
  function SelectAllFirstRow(ChK, cellno) 
{

         var gv = document.getElementById("ggvPage");
            for (var i = 1; i <= gv.rows.length - 1; i++) {
                var chk1 = gv.rows(i).cells(cellno).firstChild;
                chk1.checked = ChK.checked;
            }
 }
```

Here :
**ggvPage** is the Gridview.
**Chk** is the header Checkbox and cellno is like 1 for view,2 for Add and.........

It's working fine in IE but not in Firefox and chrome.

Please suggest some solution for fulfilling my need.

Waiting for valuable solutions,

Thanks a lot,
Supriya

Answer (score 0):

Use function .each() in jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript. It is just an example. You can modify it as per your requirement

```
 function SelectAllFirstRow(ChKAdd) 
    {
   if (ChKAdd.checked==false)
     {
      SelectCheck();
     }
    else
   {
    DeselectCheck()
    }
   }


function SelectCheck() {
        var flag;
        for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
            elm = document.forms[0].elements[i];

            if ((elm.type == 'checkbox') && (elm.name == 'chkSelectAdd') && (elm.checked == false)) {
                elm.checked = true;
                changeColor(elm);
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function DeselectCheck() {
        for (i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
            elm = document.forms[0].elements[i];

            if ((elm.type == 'checkbox') && (elm.name == 'chkSelectAdd') && (elm.checked == true)) {
                elm.checked = false;
                changeColor(elm);
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

// changes the color of the selected row

function changeColor(chkBox) {

        var rowVar = chkBox.parentNode.parentNode;
        if (chkBox.checked) {
            rowVar.style.backgroundColor = "#EDEDED";
        }
        else {
            rowVar.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        }
    }
```

where chkAdd is the name of checkbox at header which is for Add and chkSelectAdd is the names of checkboxes in GridView under Add header.

In ItemTemplate of the GridView use like this

```
<ItemTemplate>
                               <input  name="chkSelectAdd" type="checkbox" value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>'
                                        onclick='javascript: changeColor(this)' />
                           </ItemTemplate>
```